# How to persist state in redux?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

How can I save user's login information in redux?

I have tried AsyncStorage to store object but now I want to store in redux.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Redux is used to manage your app state throughout the application as a global state. Redux is not an alternative to Asyncstorage. However to persist the redux store you need to use the **Redux Persist library**

Here you can find complete documentation for that.

https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist